# Converter JSON em Array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular, typescript

Tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
let result = {"0":4,"10":4,"30":6,"60":9,"90":12,"120":15,"150":18,"180":21}
```

Preciso converter em Array no seguinte formato:

```
[{"0":4},{"10":4},{"30":6},{"60":9},{"90":12},{"120":15},{"150":18},{"180":21}]
```

Estou tentando da seguinte forma sem sucesso:

```
let dados = JSON.parse(result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let result = {"0":4,"10":4,"30":6,"60":9,"90":12,"120":15,"150":18,"180":21};

const transformation = Object.entries(result).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));

console.log(transformation);
```

---

> [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
>
> O método map() invoca a função callback passada por argumento para cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.
>
> ```
> var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
> var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
> // roots é [1, 2, 3], numbers ainda é [1, 4, 9]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente, você precisa **iterar pelas chaves e valores do objeto original separando objetos de cada um**:

```
Object.keys(result).map((key) => 
{
    let objToReturn = {};
    objToReturn[key] = result[key];
    return objToReturn;
});
```

No código acima, um `map` é feito em um array a partir de cada chave do objeto inicial, criando um novo objeto, atribuindo uma nova propriedade com o valor atual da chave do objeto inicial e retornando o novo.

O resultado seria:

```
0: {0: 4}
1: {10: 4}
2: {30: 6}
3: {60: 9}
4: {90: 12}
5: {120: 15}
6: {150: 18}
7: {180: 21}
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.